# Button to delete the android application

Tags: java, android

Is it possible thereotically to create an Android application that contains delete button within itself that deletes the app when pressed?

[image: delete picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for uninstalling the app

```html
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

          public void onClick(View view){

            Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:com.exaample.test");

            Intent uninstallIntent =
              new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
            startActivity(uninstallIntent);
          }
        });
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

yes it is you can use:

```
Uri pkgUri = Uri.parse("package:com.example");  
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,pkgUri);  
startActivity(deletelIntent);
```

hope this will help.